# how to escape "[" in velocity silent notation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, velocity

I have a checkbox in my vm file like this :

```
<input name="ISPOperatorList[0].ISPOperatorAccessStatus" id="OPERATORAccessDeny0"
                    #if( $!serviceProviderBean.ISPOperatorList[0].ISPOperatorAccessStatus == "no") checked="checked" #end
                    class="checkBoxRadio"  type="checkbox" value="no" />
```

I have added the `#if` condition to check whether a predefined "no" value comes from back-end or not. If it comes, I will make the checkbox checked.

I am getting this error while loading the page now :

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "[" at admin/ispEnrollmentPage.vm[line 203, column 91]Was expecting one of:
<RPAREN> ...
<WHITESPACE> ...
"-" ...
"+" ...
"*" ...
"/" ...
"%" ...
<LOGICAL_AND> ...
<LOGICAL_OR> ...
<LOGICAL_LT> ...
<LOGICAL_LE> ...
<LOGICAL_GT> ...
<LOGICAL_GE> ...
<LOGICAL_EQUALS> ...
<LOGICAL_NOT_EQUALS> ...
```

Comment: I think the `$` and `!` are the wrong way round in `$!serviceProviderBean` i.e. it should be `#if (!$serviceProviderBean...`

Comment: Looks like you might be using a version of Velocity that doesn't support the [] syntax.

Comment: I think Velocity generall does not support array-indices, see a similar question in a previous question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751387/

Comment: I heve got the answer now ! thanks everyone for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced a similar problem like this.
Only solution is to use `get(index)` instead of `[index]`

```
<input name="ISPOperatorList[0].ISPOperatorAccessStatus" id="OPERATORAccessDeny0"
                #if( $!serviceProviderBean.ISPOperatorList.get(0).ISPOperatorAccessStatus == "no") checked="checked" #end
                class="checkBoxRadio"  type="checkbox" value="no" />
```

Comment: oh is it ! will try it and let you know